# Group on time interval on last inserted records

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a dataset that looks like this :

```
localDateTime       |bid 
--------------------|--------
2017-09-17 15:35:05 |3085    
2017-09-17 15:35:54 |3100    
2017-09-17 15:37:05 |3100.2  
2017-09-17 15:38:06 |3101.6  
etc..
```

I want to group this by the time field and get the MAX(openBid) of each time interval and have the last 5 intervals (of 5 minutes in this example). I use this query :

```
SELECT
    MIN(localDateTime) startTime
    ,MAX(bid) maxOpenBid
    ,COUNT(*) countRecords
FROM
    Ticker
GROUP BY
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(localDateTime) DIV 300
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This gives the folowing results :

```
startTime           |maxOpenBid |countRecords
--------------------|-----------|------------
2017-09-20 10:50:03 |3306.9     |3           
2017-09-20 10:45:03 |3305       |5           
2017-09-20 10:40:04 |3304.9     |5           
2017-09-20 10:35:04 |3306       |5           
2017-09-20 10:30:03 |3303.2     |5
```

The problem that I have is that the count on the first record in the resultset counts up from 1 to 5 over the time. In this example it is 3. I want my query to have the same amount of records for all the time interval. I think the problem is that the GROUP BY on time begins at the first record of the set. Since I'm doing a ORDER BY DESC I want it to start at the last record of the set.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly - my personal approach would be to forget using the timestamps (which beside your existing problem could have missing entries due to service downtime etc) and switch to consecutive auto-incrementing numbers.  If you're feeling lazy, a auto-incrementing primary key (provided your server is set to increment in jumps of precisely 1 - MySQL clusters will break this approach) you can just do `GROUP BY FLOOR(pk_column / 5)`

Comment: Following my approach, you may have to provide an offset to "correct" the first record ... e.g. `GROUP BY FLOOR((pk_column + 4) / 5)`

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately, this still gives the same problem. It starts counting from record 1 and not from the last record back. So I still have a incomplete set for the last inserted records.

Comment: You may need to offset to account for it starting from 1.  5/5 = 1, so you’ll only get 4 in the first set (assuming you start from 1... which divided by 5 floors to 0). Try offsetting the pk field by +4 (and/or share your schemes and data if you’re stuck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, @wally put me in the right direction.

Here is what I did to make it work:

```
SET @rownr =-1;  
SELECT
    MIN(localDateTime) startTime
    ,MAX(bid) maxOpenBid
    ,COUNT(*) countRecords
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        (@rownr := (@rownr+1)) rownr
        ,ID
        ,localDateTime
        ,bid openBid
        ,ask openAsk
    FROM
        Ticker
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 25
    ) Ticker
GROUP BY
    FLOOR(rownr/5)
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Using the subquery for "Ticker" also had a really great effect on performance by generating a subset ordered by the PK.